# Name for geometric bottleneck-esque concept

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

**Loose Physical Definition**

Imagine we started with an empty polygon, $P$, and we had to completely fill it sand over time. At a specific time $t$, and a parametrization for filling $P$, $F$, we let $\partial(F,t)$ denote the amount of sand exposed to air. (i.e. the length of perimeter of the sand not touching  the edges of $P$) I'm interested in how small $\ell(F)=\sup_t \partial(F,t)$ can be. (and the name associated with the concept)

Example: If $P$ is a $a\times b$ rectangle, with $0 <a < b$, then it is fairly obvious that $\ell(F) \ge a$ over all parametrized fillings $F$.

**Formal Definition**

Let $P$ be a compact connected subset of Euclidean space.

For a closed set $N\subset P$, a homotopy from $N$ to $P$ is a continuous function $F:N\times[0,1]\to P, G(i) := \{F(x,i):x \in N\}$ such that $G(0) = N$ and $G(1)=P$. We define $\ell(F) = \sup_i \partial(G(i)) $.* We then say that $\ell(P):= \inf \ell(F)$, where $F$ is any homotopy between a closed set $N$ and $P$.

Is $\ell(P)$ a studied concept with a name?

*Formally, for $S \subset P$, I'm defining $\partial (S)$  to be $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\mu( B(S,h)\setminus S)}{h}$ where $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure and $B(S,h)$ is the set of points $x \in P$ that are within a distance of $h$ from some point $y \in S$. (this definition isn't well defined if $S$ is dense but my purposes I think it's sufficient)

Comment: It might be more straightforward to describe a "filling" of a space $P$ as a function $f:P\to[0,1]$, with the portion filled at time $t$ given by $f^{-1}([0,t])$. One can then specialize to non-pathological cases by requiring $P$ be sufficiently smooth. In this case, the boundary is given by $f^{-1}(t)$, provided $t$ is a regular value of $f$.

Comment: With that definition, if I have two exposed sides but am only filling on one side, it will not be accounted for. (i.e. if I had a $1\times 3$ rectangle, and had already filled the middle square, I could handle the left side first and then the right side, and it would seem like I had a largest exposed boundary of $1$ instead of 2)

Comment: Yes; this would be a case where $f$ is discontinuous, so the $f^{-1}(t)$ statement would not apply. Nonetheless, that process could be approximated arbitrarily well by a smooth $f$, so it stands to reason that a solution to the smooth problem could be generalized to those kinds of cases.